# Copying an extra blank page from selected Word Doc Section?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, interop, mailmerge

I've written the following code allowing users to query data based on word document that will be printed and the data source (different systems), where they can choose SOURCE1, SOURCE2, or BOTH. The data is queried, placed into an ODBC DataReader and then looped through to fill a ListView control.

I then allow users to select which records they want to print, and those records are processed into the selected word document as a Mail Merge operation.

What I am trying to do now is save each individual word document page (each record of the mail merge) to a specific folder location with its own name.

**CODE**:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lvData.Clear();
            string qryCmd = "";

            createColumns();

            switch (cmbLetterType.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    qryCmd = chkSystem("oldAddr");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    qryCmd = chkSystem("newAddr");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    qryCmd = chkSystem("nameChg");
                    break;
            }

            // If the option for BOTH is selected, qryCmd is a long string containing the individual queries for SOURCE1 and SOURCE2.
            // Here I check if a semicolon (;) exists, denoting that there are 2 cmd queries in the string.
            // If so, I split the query calling GetiSeriesData() with the first query string, then assigning qryCmd the second 
            // strings value and continuing processing as normal.
            if (qryCmd.Contains(";"))
            {
                char[] delimitChar = { ';' };
                string[] splitQueries = qryCmd.Split(delimitChar);
                qryCmd = splitQueries[0];
                GetiSeriesData(qryCmd);
                qryCmd = splitQueries[1];
            }

            GetiSeriesData(qryCmd);

            // Display message if no records found.
            if (lvData.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found.");
            }
            lblRecCnt.Text = lvData.Items.Count.ToString();
            this.lvData.CheckBoxes = true;
         }
```

---

```
public void GetiSeriesData(string query)
        {
            OdbcDataReader dr;
            try
            {
                //Set value of system based on table being looked at in ConnectionString
                string sysValue = "";
                if (query.Contains("lib1"))
                {
                    sysValue = "P";
                }
                if (query.Contains("lib2"))
                {
                    sysValue = "N";
                }

                MergeDocLibrary mdl = new MergeDocLibrary();
                dr = mdl.GetData(query);

                Int16 x = 0;
                string gndr = "";

                // Fill ListView Control lvData
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    lvData.Items.Add(dr["MEMNO"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["NAME"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ADDR1"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ADDR2"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["CITY"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["STATE"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ZIP"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ADDR1"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ADDR2"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_CITY"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_STATE"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ZIP"].ToString().Trim());

                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(sysValue.ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(DateTime.Today.ToString("d"));
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["SEX"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["LNAME"].ToString().Trim());
                    if (dr["SEX"].ToString().Trim() == "M")
                    {
                        gndr = "Mr.";
                    }
                    else // (dr["SEX"].ToString().Trim() == "F)
                    {
                        gndr = "Ms.";
                    }
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(gndr + dr["LNAME"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["CITY"].ToString().Trim() + ", " + dr["STATE"].ToString().Trim() + " " + dr["ZIP"].ToString().Trim());
                    x += 1;
                }

                mdl.closeConn();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

---

```
public void OpenAndReview()
    {
        try
        {
            string docSave = @"C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Test.doc";

        //MergeDocLibrary mdl = new MergeDocLibrary();
        //mdl.mergeDocument(docSource, docLoc);

        // Original Mail Merge Document
        Word.Range rng;
        object start = 0;
        object end = 0;
        Word.Range newWrdRng;
        Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document oWrdDoc = new Word.Document();

        // New Document Instance
        Word.Application oNewWord = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document oNewWrdDoc = new Word.Document();

        // Set 'False' in PROD, 'True' in DEV
        oWord.Visible = true;
        oNewWord.Visible = true;
        Object oTemplatePath = docLoc;

        // Open Mail Merge Doc
        oWrdDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath);

        // Open New Document
        oNewWrdDoc = oNewWord.Documents.Open(docSave);
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        // Open Mail Merge Datasource
        oWrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(docSource, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
           oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

        // Execute Mail Merge
            oWrdDoc.MailMerge.Execute();

            // Set Mail Merge Document as Active Doc
            //oWrdDoc.Activate();

            //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            MessageBox.Show(oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count.ToString());
            // 3 Records selected gives 4 Sections Counted??
            //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

            // Subtract 1 to account for the extra section being counted?

            int docCnt = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count - 1;

            int cnt = 0;
            while (cnt != docCnt)
            {
                cnt++;
                // Copy Desired Section from Mail Merge
                oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections[cnt].Range.Copy();
                // Set focus to the New Word Doc instance
                oNewWord.Activate();
                // Paste copied range to New Word Doc
                oNewWord.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Paste();
                // Save New Word Doc
                oNewWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\SuccesfullySavedDoc-" + cnt + ".doc");

                // Clear New Word Doc 
                oNewWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Select();
                oNewWord.Selection.TypeBackspace();

                // Set Mail Merge as Active Document
                oWord.Activate();
            }

        // .............

        // Save new docuemnt...?
        oNewWrdDoc.SaveAs2("SuccesfullySavedTest.doc");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
    }
    finally
    {
        //
    }
}
```

...

**EDIT3**: I've got the document clearing out with each new loop iteration. Now trying to figure out why each document is saving with an extra blank page 2.

Rough Outline:

Doc 1: Record 1 + an extra blank page (unsure why?)

Doc 2: Record 2 + an extra blank page (unsure why?)

Doc 3: REcord 3 + an extra blank page (unsure why?)

Comment: BTW, if you have complete control over the content/format of the document, you could consider using Eric White's material to generate this kind of output - it doesn't use MailMerge at all and is much more in keeping with the ".NET way of doing things" - http://ericwhite.com/blog/category/open-xml/document-generation-series/

Comment: Personally, I would consider cLosing the oNewWord Document after you have saved, creating a new one, inside the loop you have. I doubt if it will be a major performance hit.

Comment: It's an option, but I would prefer to go this route (if possible) just to conserve on a little coding and keep things understandable for whomever may fall prey to maintenance/update years down the road.

Comment: @bibadia, Got it! Now I just need to figure out the extra blank page being added to each document during Paste(). I've updated my code above.

Comment: You, it's possible you are getting the section break character at the end. I would try testing the final character in each document (could vary depending on whether it's the final section or a prior section) and deleting it. But then you need to make sure you aren't deleting headers/footers too.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

One or two of the commonly used free third-party Addins for saving as multiple, named documents do have visible VBA code, which you could consider redesigning/rewriting in C#.

What I used to use was a piece of code that executed one merge for each record in the data source. Someone posted one version of my old code [at the end of their message here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225024/word-email-merge-dynamic-subject) .

All these methods can fail for a number of reasons. The third party methods sometimes generate a single output, then split the output at every section break. That will only work for some merge types and in the case where there are no additional section breaks in the Mail Merge Main Document. "my" code only works if the merge consumes one record at a time (obviously, it can be adapted for 2 records per merge etc., but if the mail merge main document contains NEXT, NEXTIF or SKIPIF fields then the records consumed per merge can vary, and the problem then is that AFAIK it is impossible to detect how many records were consumed (unless you can rely on putting a counter in the mail merge main document.)

As for the other points, I think you need to change this part:

```
    Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document oWrdDoc = new Word.Document();

    // New Document Instance
    Word.Application oNewWord = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document oNewWrdDoc = new Word.Document();
```

because (unless C# or something else is doing something I don't know about) there is no guarantee that the new Word.Document object will be created via either of the Word.Application instances that you have just created. I think you need something more like

```
Word.Document oWrdDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(); // you may need to provide some parameters here in C#
```

Similarly for oNewWrdDoc

Once you have created those, I think the rng.FormattedText will either go away or be slightly easier to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The issue isn't in getting the Mail Merge itself to work; I have that. What I am attempting to do is process my Mail Merge, load it up on screen for user review (all the letters in 1 doc) (working!), then after review & user print (if desired), continue code processing where I will save each page of the Mail Merge word doc as it's own document in a specific location. Also, the Word.App() instances do work as intended. The line `oNewWrdDoc = oNewWord.Documents.Open(docSave)` uses the oNewWrdDoc instance and loads up that document inside it.

Comment: OK, I've seen your changes & can also see that my merge-per-record suggestion wasn't relevant.

What problem do you now get if you use

oNewWrdDoc.Range.FormattedText = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections[1].Range.FormattedText;

(In VBA, it works OK here, but I think you will only get headers/footers for section 1 - to get them across as well, if you have them, you may have to copy ranges from more than one storyrange)

Comment: Give me a minute to insert EDIT. I've made more progress.

Comment: See EDIT. I'm now trying to clear out my Word Doc instance during each loop for the next records (Mail Merge Section) processing.